# Cannot use sessions when working with multiple databases

Tags: django, database, session, multiple-databases

It seems impossible to use sessions in my configuration of multiple databases. For example, I always need to type username and password when I enter the admin site. How do I make sessions work?

I have two databases, one for each language:

```
# settings.py

DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'ru': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'db_ru.sqlite3',
    },
    'en': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'db_en.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

This is the middleware stack that I use:

```
# settings.py

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'me.middleware.database_routing.RouterMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

I set the next router in `settings.py`:

```
# settings.py
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['me.middleware.database_routing.DatabaseRouter']
```

And here is the router code:

```
# database_routing.py

import threading
from django.http import Http404
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

request_cfg = threading.local()

class RouterMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        lang = request.LANGUAGE_CODE
        if any(lang == i[0] for i in settings.LANGUAGES):
            request_cfg.lang = lang
        else:
            raise Http404()

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if hasattr(request_cfg, 'lang'):
            del request_cfg.lang
        return response

class DatabaseRouter(object):
    def _default_db(self):
        if hasattr(request_cfg, 'lang') and request_cfg.lang in settings.DATABASES:
            return request_cfg.lang
        else:
            return 'default'

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return self._default_db()

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return self._default_db()

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        db_list = ('default', 'ru', 'en')
        if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        return True
```

Comment: I'd recommend copy/pasting the code in your new question, because a lot of users won't give your question a chance if they don't see any relevant code.  Anyways, +1

Comment: Also, can you show your `DatabaseRouter`?  That is imperative to answer your question.

Comment: @CalebGoodman, Stackoverflow doesn't let me add more code because of the "question is mostly code" constraint

Comment: RIP...  Looks like I shot you in the foot by posting your `settings.py` :( sorry about that.

Comment: @CalebGoodman Maybe I should post the code of `DatabaseRouter` and somehow summarize `settings.py`?

Comment: That could work.  Or you could add more to explain things you've tried, unexpected results, etc.  (Not that I think your question needs it necessarily)

Comment: Something tells me that the issue is related to the usage of threading...

Comment: Removing `process_response()` method from `RouterMiddleware` seems to be a workaround, but I don't know if it's the true solution.

Comment: Why do you need separate databases for each language?  Have you considered using Django's [translator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#translation)?